# Solr Faceting Multi-valued vs Tokenizers

Tags: solr

I'm trying to set up a subject field in my schema. I'm drawing from a database where a single record can have multiple subjects and the subjects are listed in a comma delimited string. Is there a way to facet on just one of the subjects?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean: "is it possible to facet, while filtering by one of the subjects" OR "is it possible to facet on subject field" OR something completely different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if I understand well you want this, in the dih file:

```
        <entity name="entity"  pk="id" query="..." transformer="RegexTransformer">
          <field column="subjects" splitBy=","/>
        </entity>
```

and the query for facetting:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/select?q=...&facet=true&facet.field=subjects&facet.query=subjects:the-one-you-want
```

would that work?

Answer (score 1):

Check [SolrFacetingOverview](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrFacetingOverview) for an faceting overview.
Facet Indexing section mentions the field type you should choose for the field that you want to facet on.

You can customize the faceting using [SimpleFacetParameters](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SimpleFacetParameters)

You can filter the results with entities having particular value for a subject using the [filter query](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CommonQueryParameters#fq) e.g. `fq=subject:"MATH"`
The filtering would produce only the results matching the criteria and the facet results would include the facets from the resultset.